# How to design a decision circuit with LEDs

Tags: diodes

I have designed a circuit to charge a battery with 5v DC.

I need a decision circuit to check on the battery to see whether it has charged fully or not by using two LEDs; red and green

Comment: How are you planning on doing it?

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I am going to assume your charging circuit is fine as you are only asking about the 'monitoring' side of the circuit. Really, all you need to do is monitor voltages.

Personally, I find the easiest way to do things like this is by using comparators. Use a reference voltage, check it against the battery voltage, then the comparator goes high once the voltage level is reached.

A good read up on [comparators](http://www.circuitstoday.com/voltage-comparator) can be found HERE which was really useful when I was a beginner. Using a non-inverting comparator allows you to put a reference voltage on the non inverting input. When the voltage rises above the threshold of the inverting input, the comparator will saturate to the positive rail. An example can be seen here:
[image]

If you want LEDs to come on at different times, use more than one comparator and have different LEDs come on at different times. It will be up to you to figure out your voltage levels, but it isn't a hard task. Only thing to add is it is usually a good idea to have the comparators turn LEDs on and off by toggling an N channel MOSFET or some similar configuration.

Using the information in this answer should allow you to design a circuit that will perform the task you need.

Comment: To make sure the LEDs aren't flickering at a certain threshold voltage I'd suggest a Schmitt Trigger instead of a simple comparator so you have a hystersis.

Comment: @Humpawumpa yeah, a Schmitt trigger would probably be best, but we try not to make the site a design service, so for such questions, I tend to give a simplistic solution that people can build on and start to develop themselves